# retrieving matching rows between two data frames using for loop

Tags: r

I have been trying to do this but not getting anywhere. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(chrom = "chr1", start=c(10,20,30), end = c(100,200,300), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(chrom = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3"),start=c(15,500,150), end = c(75,1000,300), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to get all rows of df2 where `df1$chrom == df2$chrom`. Or better yet: I want to generate the output in a new vector and display the rows of df1 followed by df2 or vice versa where `df1$chrom == df2$chrom`.

I have tried this using a for loop as follows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
    x[i] <- df2[which(df1$chrom == df2$chrom[i])]
}
```

Not working!

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish in doing this comparison between data frames? There may just be an easier solution to your work flow than the approach you're taking--i.e., if you only want a vector out of a data frame, are you going to require many such vectors? A new data frame? What is the end-goal? That context is important to the questions you ask.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
df2[df2$chrom == df1$chrom, ]
#   chrom start end
# 1  chr1    15  75
```

Per your comment, you might also want to try the following.

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 'chrom')
```

This will do a database "join" on the two frames ("tables"). The result is this.

```
  chrom start.x end.x start.y end.y
1  chr1      10   100      15    75
2  chr1      20   200      15    75
3  chr1      30   300      15    75
```

It isn't always an efficient approach to take in R, but it is convenient. You can control the ".x" stuff with parameters (see the help pages: ?merge). If you want all the fields from df2 included, you could add the "all = TRUE" parameter setting to merge.

As I alluded to before, it is best to consider the overall approach. This isn't necessarily an efficient way to process your data because now you've entered a lot of redundancy into the resulting frame. Instead, in database terms, we think of df2 as a "look up" table. The "chr1" in df1 references information in df2 (a foreign key) that is associated with df1 but distinct from it. Instead of, as the merge above shows, having the information of df2 repeated, we can simply access it when required. This is where the merge makes that convenient.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the format that I want. It will be nice to have the matching rows of both data frames side by side in a new data frame with 6 columns. Actually my ultimate goal is much more complicated where the comparison will be done satisfying many conditions between the two data frames. The above condition is just one of them.

Comment: The statement you sent works very well. Thanks. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it...but it works! Thank you so much

Comment: It's at first hard to get (particularly if you're used to another language that uses loops) but once you get it it's pretty straight forward.  if you have multiple conditions remember `%in%` and the logical operators `&` and `|` are great tools in indexing which is the method Bryan showed (rather than an explicit loop).

Comment: Would `df2[df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom, ]` be more robust in this circumstance?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Tyler. Its kinda complicated to explain what I am trying to do....and its harder because I am very new with R. I will work on it a bit more and hopefully my next post will makes more sense. Anyways thanks for taking the time.......

Comment: User, to understand what is going on you have to think about vectors. For instance, the '$' operator grabs the column on the RHS as-a-vector from the data frame on the LHS. Thus, df2$chrom specifies the column chrom from df2 as a vector. It is the same as df2[, 'chrom'] (the comma is important!!). Now, the "==" logical operator returns a logical vector. It looks at each instance of the vector df2$chrom and compares it element-wise to df1$chrom. Assuming they are vectors of length N, then "==" returns a Boolean vector of length N.

Comment: Part of the "[" indexing of a data frame, you can specify things numerically. For instance, if "chrom" is the 4th column in df2, then I could have done df[, 4], also. I could also be explicit about what rows I want. For instance, if I used which(...) on the boolean vector, I'd get one of length K, for K number of TRUEs that were in it. The function which returns the numeric position of those TRUEs. Thus, if they were 2 and 10, then df2[c(2, 10), 'chrom'] would return the same thing as the example I provided. Get it? Just look at each part of the code piece-wise to uncover what is going on.